# Only replace the first x instances in a row in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In pandas dataframe and just want to replace the first 3 instances of a string going from the top of a particular column to the bottom.

| Procedure[Trial] |
| --- |
| overinclusion2 |
| overinclusion2 |
| overinclusion2 |
| cowion2 |
| horsen2 |
| overinclusion2 |

I have tried this and thought this would work, but it still replaces EVERY instance of the string in the column, what obvious thing am I missing here?...

`df['Procedure[Trial]'] = df['Procedure[Trial]'].str.replace('overinclusion2','oi_1',3)`

The column is much longer than this, but effectively I want to only replace the first 3 instances of 'overinclusion' but I am still replacing all of them?  This is what my output looks like.

| Procedure[Trial] |
| --- |
| oi_1 |
| oi_1 |
| oi_1 |
| cowion2 |
| horsen2 |
| oi_1 |

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example for clarity (input+output)?

Comment: Sure tried to above, sorry if it's in table format, but I think it gives the idea.

Comment: Are the matches always exact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the matches are exact, you can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m = df['Procedure[Trial]'].eq('overinclusion2')

df.loc[m & m.cumsum().le(3), 'Procedure[Trial]'] = 'oi_1'
```

Output:

```
  Procedure[Trial]
0             oi_1
1             oi_1
2             oi_1
3          cowion2
4          horsen2
5   overinclusion2
```

Alternative:

```
df.loc[df.index[df['Procedure[Trial]'].eq('overinclusion2')][:3],
       'Procedure[Trial]'] = 'oi_1'
```

Comment: I think these would both work, but thank you!

Comment: This does seem overly complicated for pandas :( but it works

Comment: I added another option that doesn't require a `cumsum`. I don't think those are *complicated*, but as you don't have a builtin for what you want to do, you need to code the logic yourself ;)

Comment: Thanks all these answers worked.  My appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `cumsum()` to count the number of times the desired word to replace appears.

```
s = df['Procedure[Trial]']

s.mask(s.eq('overinclusion2').cumsum().le(3),s.replace({'overinclusion2':'oi_2'}))
```

Output:

```
0              oi_2
1              oi_2
2              oi_2
3           cowion2
4           horsen2
5    overinclusion2
```